Yacc/Lex: "Undefined symbol 'DELETE' and 'NUMBER' in Lex file" during compilation
I'm working on a simple parser using Yacc and Lex. When trying to compile, I get the following errors:
parcial1.l:10:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DELETE'
parcial1.l:11:10: error: no member named 'num' in 'union YYSTYPE'
parcial1.l:11:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NUMBER'

here's the relevant parts from the lex file:
%%

"add"            { return ADD; }
"list"           { return LIST; }
"delete"         { return DELETE; }
[0-9]+           { yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; } 
\"[^\"]+\"       { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return STRING; }  
[ \t\n]+         { /* Ignore whitespace */ }

%%


And from the yacc file:
%union {
    int num;
    char* str;
}

%token ADD 
%token LIST 
%token DELETE
%token <str> STRING
%token <num> NUMBER


I believe identifiers and members have been properly declared so I cannot find why this error is showing.
Running in Mac M1 Sonoma 14.6.1
bison (GNU Bison) 2.3
flex 2.6.4 Apple(flex-34)

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

The #include lines are a relevant parts of the Yacc file.  Likewise for the Flex file.
